# WSDL именовые параметры

Tags: wsdl, массивы

Добрый день, столкнулся с проблемой. Серверу требуется передать запрос

```
$param=array(
    'client'=>'15489996',
    'key'=>'155asd5asd6a9sd9asd9qd',
    'value'=>'7777788889999',
    );

$wsdl=new SoapClient('http://site.ru/service?wsdl');
$res=$wsdl->__soapCall('GetSomethig',$param);
```

В результате отправляется следуещее

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:GetSomethig/>
    <param1>155asd5asd6a9sd9asd9qd</param1>
    <param2>7777788889999</param2>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Проблема в том, что вместо param1,...  должны быть ключи из массива. Да и в [доках](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php) об этом говориться на случай ассоциативного массива

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$param=array(
    new SoapParam('15489996','client'),
    new SoapParam('155asd5asd6a9sd9asd9qd','key'),
    new SoapParam('7777788889999','value'),
    );
```